# Two versions of class equation

Tags: group-theory, definition

I have seen two versions of class equation.

1. If $\bar{x}_1$, ..., $\bar{x}_m$ where $x \in G$ are distinct conjugacy classes of $G$, then $|G|= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{m} [G:C_G(x_i)]$.
2. Sometimes it can be written as $|G|= |C(G)|+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{m} [G:C_G(x_i)]$.

I understand that these two are basically the same, but any subtle difference here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are of course the same, provided you make it clear that in the second one $x_{i}$ ranges over the *non-central* classes. And then, the second version is used for instance when proving that a finite, non trivial group of order the power of a prime has non-trivial centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As @AndreadCaranti points out in his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233206/two-versions-of-class-equation#comment6651165_3233206) . . .*

These two results are the same, given that, in the second, the $x_i$ ranges over all non-central classes.

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is the number of all the conjugacy classes, then the second one is wrong, as it counts twice the singletons.